# How to handle 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python, object, handle, nonetype

In the following code how I can handle  `t[4].find("a")["href"].split('/')[4]` if is null or not available!

Note: this code is in extend block.

```py
PlayersTransferhistoryResult.extend([
{
   "pId": pid[4],
   "Season": t[0].text.strip(),
   "Date": t[1].text.strip(),
   "Left": t[4].text.strip(),
   "LeftId": t[4].find("a")["href"].split('/')[4],
   "Joined": t[7].text.strip(),
   "JoinedId": t[7].find("a")["href"].split('/')[4],
   "MV": t[8].text.strip(),
   "Fee": t[9].text.strip(),
} for t in (t.find_all(recursive=False) for t in tr) ])
```

Comment: That depends on what you want the value of the `LeftId` field to be if `t[4].find("a")` returns `None`.

Comment: Sometimes t [7] is a link and no problem. But in some cases t [7] is not a link and I encounter the above error

Comment: In any case, you have to *check* the values, rather than just assuming they aren't `None`.

Comment: That's my question! How?

Comment: It's not that hard. Start by writing your code with an explicit `for` loop, and use `if` statements to control whether or not you try to access the `href` attribute of the result from `find`.